# Elasticsearch Watermark Settings

Tags: elasticsearch

Would it be possible to set elasticsearch high watermark low watermark? My reasoning is that I don't want one node to be stuck with all the days active shards (which I think would happen if low watermark is breached - the low node will get all the new shards that are being allocated out of an 8 node cluster), but the disk space among my nodes is screwed up and some nodes are much lower then others. So my thought is once high watermark is breached, it will relocate other shards which should be fine with me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

But seriously... I don't see why not:
the [ES help](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/disk.html) says it would just stop allocating new disk space once the `cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low` is reached and it would start moving them once the `cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high` is reached. So this would just mean that it would stop allocating disk space and start moving shards off at the same time.

However, it could lead to some [issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis) if the threshold is zero...